# Methods to create curved lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, drawing

I'm looking for help in creating curved lines in the example below:

[image]

I've tried using rounded rectangles but it the final result doesn't look quite the same.

Comment: Can you show us what you *did* come up with (and how you did it). This will better help us help you.

Answer (score 7):

## A **blend**...

Draw a rounded rectangle...
<sup>(Or a regular rectangle and then round two corners equally.)</sup>
Just a stroke and no fill....

[image]

Delete sections of the shape by using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select them and then hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image]

Using the **Blend Tool**, click the top anchor on the left (1), then the top anchor on the right (2). This tells Illustrator what anchor to blend to what anchor, creating a proper blend.
<sub>Note that if you merely use the menu to create the blend, the path directions will result in one side being seen as "flipped" and will result a blend which is unexpected. Using the Blend Tool to specificy the anchors to blend to/from circumvents the issue with path directions.</sub>

[image]

[image]

Then choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` from the menu. Set the Blend Options **Spacing** to **Specified Steps** in the drop down menu, then enter the number of iterations you want.

[image]

As a **live** blend you can further refine by moving the anchor points of the two paths around.

[image]

Then, for separate, individual paths, select the entire object, choose `Object > Expand` from the menu, and simply click `OK`.

[image]

The end result is a **group** of strokes following the curves smoothly. You can then *ungroup* if necessary.

---

Answer (score 1):

Rounded rectangles seems... a laborious approach to me; I'd just draw 'em with the bézier pen tool.

[image]